# Keyspace event in AWS Redis

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis

I have enabled the "notify-keyspace-events" for redis node, and getting the event published on key change on subscription.

But, I want to understand, what redis does with the events to be published if there are no subscribers to any key.

Any information or links, which could help me understand will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is a fire and forget model. If there are no subscribers available, it will drop those events. It will even drop even if the subscriber is not available or will not be able to take those events.

Documentation from Redis:

https://redis.io/topics/notifications

Snippet from documentation,

> Because Redis Pub/Sub is fire and forget currently there is no way to
>   use this feature if your application demands reliable notification of
>   events, that is, if your Pub/Sub client disconnects, and reconnects
>   later, all the events delivered during the time the client was
>   disconnected are lost.